# Dart: How to Encode Decode animated webp files?

Tags: flutter, dart, webp

I am trying to decode animated webp image file and encode it's frames to animated webp image file in Dart (cli)

**Dart Code:**

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

void main() {
    final image = 'asset/test.webp';

    File bytes = File(image);
    List<int> list = bytes.readAsBytesSync();

    var anim = decodeWebPAnimation(list)!;

    var obj = WebPEncoder();

    for (var frame in anim) {
      obj.addFrame(frame, duration: 1);
    }

    var finished = obj.finish();

    print(finished); // [] empty, no frames get added
    // final encodedAnim = obj.encodeAnimation(); 

    File('asset/output.webp').writeAsBytesSync(finished!,
      flush: true); // pass something like encodeWebp(input)
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
dependencies:
    image: ^3.1.3
```

**input file**: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WhatsApp/stickers/main/Android/app/src/main/assets/2/07_OK.webp

**Output:**
There is zero frame after calling `finish()`, so the output image file is invalid. i.e. file size: 0 byte

**Ref of Dart APIs:**

*WebpEncoder*:
https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/WebPEncoder-class.html

*DecodeWebpAnimation*: https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/decodeWebPAnimation.html

What went wrong? How to fix this? or would suggest any library?
Thank You!

Comment: Can you share that webp file here?

Comment: yes edited the answer with image link

Comment: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/6 The library you’re trying to use doesnt support webp encoding for now.